# software transaction memory(STM) vs compare and swap(CAS)

Tags: multithreading, concurrency

I have been going through STM for concurrency without traditional locks, it explains about comparing the shared values before committing it to the shared values permanently.

CAS also does the same thing.threads obtain a copy of the data they want to change and apply their changes, under the optimistic assumption that no other thread will have made changes to the shared memory in the meantime. When this optimistic assumption holds true, the thread just managed to update shared memory without locking. When this assumption is false, the work was wasted, but still no locking was applied.

Is CAS and STM used interchgingly or what is the difference in between these two??

Comment: Your thinking crosses several layers of abstraction.  CAS is an extremely low-level primitive that is used in concurrency control.  You can use CAS to implement traditional locks, which are a higher-level mechanism, and you can use traditional locks to implement software transaction memory, which is a higher-level still.

Answer (score 1):

CAS only works on a single location, whereas STM typically permits sparse data structures to be updated.   Both of these have higher level abstractions.
CAS, briefly, simulates an atomic read-modify-write cycle on architectures that disallow such operations.   RMW does not scale well.  The simulation involves three steps:  claim ownership of a cache line, determine the new data to be written to this line, rewrite the location if the ownership claim is still in effect.   Because the operation is conditional, it can fail either because the comparison failed, or the cache line was revoked during the operation.

STM builds upon this to support N cache lines.  The mechanisms in modern cpus are a bit dodgy, but proceed something like this:

```
while (1) {
     setjmp(current_pc).
     update locations 1 thru N.
     if (commit()) {
          break;
     }
}
```

The updates are not visible outside of this core unless the commit succeeds for all locations.   So, you could walk through a linked list, reversing the pointers in the list, yet all the changed nodes would only appear in your cache until the commit, at which point the entire list would atomically change for any observer.  At any point between the setjmp and commit anything that would cause the transaction to fail will rewind the cpu back to the setjmp point.  This rewind will abandon all of the updates.

As you note, there is a cost to this, namely I might have to reiterate the while loop an arbitrary number of times.  In practice it is worse.

N, the number of locations to update cannot exceed the size of the private cache; this magic only works by having the cache refuse to publish the updates until the transaction is complete, so needs to store the data in this cache.

Caches typically have a limited associativity, for example a SkyLake L1 cache is 8-way associative.  In the linked list above, suppose 9 of the nodes happened to collide on one cache bucket; the transaction is destined to fail, because there is no where to store this 9th entry.  The outer level while loop won’t help; you will be stuck in a loop unless you provide a second implementation of the list update that does not use the STM mechanism.  Now you have two problems.

Suppose an interrupt occurs in the middle of your transaction, and starts a new transaction.  They don’t nest.

The hardware implementation of STM leaves something to be desired as a general mechanism; however as a point solution for kernel internals it has a great deal of promise.

Comment: so STM is an overall an architecture that treats events as transactions and CAS is the mechanism through which which can gain STM??